# How to subscribe to different apps with different channels?

Tags: api, streaming-api

I am creating a system that integrate with the companys' salesforce data using the streamingpAPI and the subscriber model. What I understand is if an app input to my system the `consumer key` and the `secret key` I will then be capable of streaming with their system and integrate the two system together (given that my system is external and not on salesforce).

My question here:

Is it possible to subscribe to different companies? I mean if more than one company input its `consumer key` and `secret key` to my system so that I can integrate, can I subscribe to all of them? Or is one channel only capable of streaming for one company?

Answer (score 1):

Its not completely clear to me what you are describing. It sounds like you have an external Application that a Salesforce Org would create what we call a *Connected App* (related to their specific Org) to connect to your Application. I'd typically expect something else instead, but am using your terminology.

If that is the case, each unique org would generate their own unique consumer key and secret key for their Salesforce Connected App to connect to your Application. That is what would allow them to identify their feed as being unique when you subscribe to it and they send data to you.

That should allow you to identify and subscribe to feeds from different Orgs through your Application. It is your integration that would need to keep track of where the feeds are coming from as they come into your Application. That is all I can tell you without knowing more about the details of your actual Application.

Comment: yes i mean when the org create a connected app and pass the consumer and secret key in a form from a website to my system i can then use both of them to connect to their org data , but my question here is when my server subscribe to the salesforce is it only one subscribtion and using this subscribtion i can get data from many org ? or i create different subscribtion in my code to each org ? i am lost , and sorry if i ask silly questions here

Comment: You will need to create a different subscription via the unique consumer and secret keys provided for use with Connected Apps originating from each individual Org you want to connect and receive data from. Each org will need to create a Connected App and send you the consumer and secret keys in order for you to connect with that Org's App.